# How to property link a docker container to a external mysql container?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to make a web server container connect with a mysql-server container, but i'm getting unknown host when I try to connect at mysql server, like the phpmyadmin.

Here my mysql docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        env_file:
            - ".env"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        expose:
            - "3306"
        volumes:
            - "./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

And here my web server container

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: web
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
            - "./etc/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled"
            - "./etc/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
            - "./data/domains:/domains"
        depends_on:
            - php
        external_links:
            - "mysql:mysql"
    php:
        image: nanoninja/php-fpm
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - "./etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
            - "./web:/var/www/html"
            - "./data/domains:/domains"
    myadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
        restart: always
        external_links:
            - "mysql:mysql"
```

Did I setup the docker-compose files correctly?

Edit 1:

```
root@server:~/docker# docker ps | grep mysql
0d49167a6aae        mysql                                            "docker-entrypoint..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                     mysql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are using two different compose files. The `external_links` doesn't work anymore if you don't have both containers on same network. See below from documentation

> If you’re using the version 2 or above file format, the externally-created containers must be connected to at least one of the same networks as the service which is linking to them. Starting with Version 2, links are a legacy option. We recommend using networks instead.
>
> This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a (version 3) Compose file.

**Using host IP**

Since your mysql is running on the host mapped 3306 also. In your compose file you can add

```
extra_hosts:
  - "mysql:<MACHINEIP>"
```

MachineIP is the IP of your host. Again not a recommended way to do it

**Using external networks**

`docker-compose` allows you to define networks. So you can define that in your mysql compose file and then map it as an external network in your other docker-compose and have access to the same using its name `mysqldb`

Refer to this url https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#using-a-pre-existing-network

Comment: Thank you, i didn't realize that this name needs to be the same, because i used container_name option. I will try those changes;

Comment: That was my bad, I didn't see you used `container_name`. Give me a few mins

Comment: Corrected my answer